# GitLab not working w/ Nginx

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I am trying to get GitLab setup with my current installation of Nginx but I keep getting an Error 502. I have included my configuration files, and not sure what I am doing wrong. But I followed the "Using a non-bundled web-server" steps on https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md

/etc/nginx/conf.d/gitlab-omnibus-nginx.conf
http://pastebin.com/bQ8eCiNh

/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
http://pastebin.com/Lw5tjwXy

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 502 means "The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and received an invalid response from the upstream server."  So there are two possibilities here.

1. Your Gitlab server is not actually working or is returning an invalid response. After starting the Gitlab server, use `sudo netstat -plnt` and make sure it is running on a port and note the port. Then connect directly to this port in your browser (or from the CLI on the server if necessary) and confirm that Gitlab is working fine without a proxy in front of it. If Gitlab is running on a socket and not a port, [there are also tools to test HTTP servers through socket connections](http://blog.willj.net/2011/12/02/testing-http-over-socket-connections-with-socat/) that you can use.
2. Nginx is not configured correctly to connect to Gitlab. In this case, check your Nginx error log to see if there is any more detail besides the "502" error.